# Highcharts default scale interval are different in case of backbone and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, highcharts

Though Y-Axis default value of min, max and tickInterval are taken 'null'. But charts appear different in case of backbone and in angularjs. Exactly same data are being used in both and same value of min, max and tickInterval. Please, find attached image here.

In Backbone:
[image]
In AngularJS:
[image]

```
var yAxis = [{
                'min': null,
                'max': null,
                'tickInterval': null,

                title: {
                    text: 'Y-Axis',
                    style: {
                        color: ''
                    }
                }
}]
```

If anybody could suggest, then it would be really helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reproduce it somehow? On the attached images, the data seems to be different.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel data are exactly same, please have a look of images

Comment: Ok, so could you reproduce it somehow in the online code editor?